# How to debug servlet using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Have a servlet and it can run inside TomCat. However, I am not sure how to debug it inside Eclipse(Java Standard version). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First ensure that you're using ["Eclipse IDE for **Enterprise** Java Developers"](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), with the **Enterprise** in its name, and thus very definitely not just "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".

Once ensured/upgraded, put breakpoints in the servlet code the usual way and run the server in debug modus. Rightclick the server in Eclipse and choose *Debug* instead of *Start* (or click the bug button instead of the green arrow on the button panel of the servers view). Then fire a HTTP request on the servlet using your favourite webbrowser. Eclipse will open and focus the debug panel when the particular code line with the breakpoint is about to be executed.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on project -> Debug as -> Debug on server should do the trick