# Debugging a library I wrote (deployed as JAR file) that is used by 3rd party client

Tags: java, file, debugging, jar, javabeans

I am using an application that allows me to insert business logic via a JavaBean, in the form of a JAR file.  The problem is, I want to be able to set breakpoints in my code, to troubleshoot it.  But it has been deployed to the 3rd party app, as a JAR file.

At runtime of the 3rd party app, is it possible to make my app look and behave as a JAR file, with the ability to debug it?

I hope that is a clear enough explanation.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305744/how-to-debug-servlet-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to run this 3rd-party app with remote debugging turned on by adding the following to the JVM arguments:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

and then attach to it from your development environment.  If this is Eclipse, then you just create a new `Remote Java Application` debug configuration (`Run` -> `Debug Configurations...`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It turns out that for my application, I needed to setup the 3rd party software to run in client mode, not server, since I wanted my JAR file to break, when the library was being accessed.  But you definitely set me on the right path. The command line that worked for me was : java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8000.  And then in eclipse, I used connection type = (Socket Listen).  Thanks again! Much appreciated!! -Paul

Comment: Hi @user3726164 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks David, I missed that.  Question has been answered.